# Count number of Variables Missing per Value in Column

Tags: r, csv

I currently have a csv that is loaded as a dataframe into R with 2500 observations and 49 columns. The data looks like the following:

```
    Donor Year Amount
World Bank 2006 94,000
World Bank 2007 
World Bank      80,000
```

I am trying to get a count of all the missing values in the csv by donor (which is a column) and then divide it by the total observations to get the ratio of missing data per donor.

For the above example, which has 2 missing fields and 9 total fields, the math would look something like this:

2NA/9total fields.

```
donor_empty_iati<- group_by(chad_iati, reporting.org)
summary_donor_empty_iati <- summarise(donor_empty_iati, count_empty = length(which(n==""|n==" ")), total_by_donor = count_empty/nrow*49)

order_summary_donor_empty_iati <- summary_donor_empty_iati[order(-summary_donor_empty_iati$total_by_donor),]
```

Any help to quickly do this using a summarize or function would be really helpful.

Comment: But, these 2NA values are from two columns.

Comment: correct so it is finding the total NA values per value in a column, so total NA values per World Bank in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this with `data.table`.  Convert the "data.frame" to "data.table" using `setDT`.  Get the "count" (`.N`) of grouping variable ("Donor").  By default, the column will be named as "N".  Instead of working with "wide" format, it may be better in this case to reshape the columns to single column "V2" (`unlist(.SD)`.  Grouped by "Donor", we can get the total number of `NAs`in "V2" (`sum(is.na(V2))`) and divide it by the sum of `.N` (which will be 6 for the two columns) and "N" (3).

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, list(.N,unlist(.SD)), Donor][, 
                    list(Count=sum(is.na(V2))/(.N+N[1])), Donor]
 #      Donor     Count
 #1: World Bank 0.2222222
```

Or a `base R` solution using `split` and `vapply`.  Split the dataset by "Donor" column and get the sum of NA values (`is.na(x)` returns a matrix) divided by the length of `as.matrix(x)` (i.e. 9)

```
  vapply(split(df, df$Donor), 
         function(x) sum(is.na(x))/length(as.matrix(x)), double(1L))
  #World Bank 
  #0.2222222
```

Or as suggested by @Marat Talipov

```
  vapply(split(df, df$Donor), 
      function(x) mean(is.na(x)), double(1L))
```

Comment: that worked. Thank you so much! ended up using the vapply result.

Comment: I guess you could use `mean(is.na(x))` here

Answer (score 1):

missing <- sum(is.na(df$Donor))
missing